# The following C code outputs a segmentation fault error which I can hardly understand why

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void append(char* s, char n);
void splitstr(char* string);

int main()
{
    splitstr("COMPUTE 1-1");
    printf("\n");
    splitstr("COMPUTE 1+1");
    printf("\n");
    splitstr("COMPUTE 1*1");
    return 0;
}

void append(char* s, char ch) {
    while(*s != '\0'){
        s = s + 1;
    }
    *s = ch;
    s = s + 1;
    *s = '\0';
}

void splitstr(char* string){
    int count = 1;
    char* expression = "";
    while(*string != '\0'){
        if(count > 8){
            append(expression, *string);
            string = string + 1;
            count = count + 1;
        }else{
            string = string + 1;
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",expression);
}
```

Example Input and Output:
Input: COMPUTE 1+1
Output: 1+1
Input: COMPUTE 2-6
Output: 2-6

Originally, this code does not include stdio.h (I am doing this for testing on an online C compiler) because I am building an OS from scratch so I need to write all the functions by myself. I think the problem might be in the append function but I cannot find it.

Comment: How far does it get before segfaulting?

Comment: You never allocate any memory for `append` to write to.

Comment: `char* expression = (char*) malloc(...);`

Comment: allocate memory using malloc works! Thank you guys so much! But sadly I can't figure out how to write a malloc function from scratch tho I will try to do so definitely.

Comment: @KurtWeber My OS is very simple which booted in 16-bit real-mode and load the kernel in 32-bit protected mode (I've done print string, read keyboard, handle interrupts, etc...) and what I am currently do is working on a simple shell for my Operating System, I want it to have a basic function of a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of
`char* expression = "";`
do
`char[MAX_expression_length+1] expression;`

or use realloc in the append function

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the culprit:

```
append(expression, *string);
```

Notice how `expression` is declared:

```
char* expression = "";
```

In other words, `expression` consists of one byte, a single `\0`.  Right away, we can see that `append()` won't work like you want it to--the `while` loop will never run, because `*s` is already `\0`.

But beyond that, the segfault likely happens at the bottom of `append()`.  After the while loop, you unconditionally increment `s` and then write to the location it now points to.  The problem is that this is a location that has never been allocated (since `s` is a reference to `splitstr()`'s `expression`, which is a single byte long).  Furthermore, because `expression` is declared as a string constant, depending on your platform it may be placed in an area of memory marked read-only.  Consequently, this is an attempt to write into memory that may not actually belong to the process and may also not be writable, raising the fault.

Answer (score 0):

`expression` points to a *string literal*, and trying to modify a string literal leads to undefined behavior.

You need to define `expression` as an *array* of `char` large enough to store your final result:

```
char expression[strlen(string)+1]; // VLA
```

Since your result isn’t going to be any longer than the source string, this should be sufficient (provided your implementation supports VLAs).